# make operators overloading less redundant in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I'm writing a class overloading the list type.
I just wrote this and I'm wondering if there exists any other way less redundant to do it :

```
class Vector:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        #Vector([1, 2, 3]) * 5 => Vector([5, 10, 15])
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            tmp = list()
            for i in self.l:
                tmp.append(i * other)
            return Vector(tmp)
        raise VectorException("We can only mul a Vector by a scalar")

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        #Vector([1, 2, 3]) / 5 => Vector([0.2, 0.4, 0.6])
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            tmp = list()
            for i in self.l:
                tmp.append(i / other)
            return Vector(tmp)
        raise VectorException("We can only div a Vector by a Scalar")

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        #Vector([1, 2, 3]) // 2 => Vector([0, 1, 1])
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            tmp = list()
            for i in self.l:
                tmp.append(i // other)
            return Vector(tmp)
        raise VectorException("We can only div a Vector by a Scalar")
```

As you can see, every overloaded method is a copy/paste of the previous with just small changes.

Comment: Why don't you use list comprehensions? `return Vector(i*other for i in self.l)` is much more compact than your four lines. As for `isinstance`, why not let Python itself raise `TypeError`?

Comment: This is a good place to use the Strategy pattern.

Comment: The less redundant way is to `import numpy`

Comment: I believe the "correct" way to do these is to return `NotImplemented` instead of raising the error, check out [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you mind if I make it a part of my answer? (With a proper reference to your comment.)

Comment: @DyZ go ahead I don't mind

Comment: I notice that, in addition to the one change in the expression, there's also a change in the comment at the start of the body. You probably want a docstring rather than a comment there, because users can actually see a docstring by typing `help(Vector)`, while nobody will see the comment unless they read your source code. (Also, generating the appropriate docstring for each method is a fun little exercise.)

Comment: As a side note: If you really want to simulate the list type, you probably want to make your class a `collections.abc.MutableSequence`. That won't help with this problem, but it will help with some other things, like automatically generating 11 `list`-like methods for you.

Comment: One more thing: Your type really isn't quite simulating a `list` (or a `MutableSequence`), because they already have `+` and `*` methods. For example, `Vector([1,2,3]) * 3` would have to give you `Vector([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])` to act like `[1, 2, 3]`, and it obviously can't do that. That's (part of) the reason `numpy` arrays aren't considered sequences and don't try to act like lists or tuples (or anything more specific than indexable iterables).

Comment: Then I'd re-raise wim's suggestion that you try `numpy` here. Especially if you've never used it before. Of course it's also worth learning how to code up something like this for yourself, but _doing_ clever things with matrices and vectors is going to come up a lot more often than _implementing_ clever matrix and vector classes.

Comment: Don't edit your question in a way that completely invalidates the answers. You asked a question. Don't then edit the question to make the answers nonsensical. I've rolled your question back to its original form and readded the tag that smci added; in the future, don't do that again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want to do here is dynamically generate the methods. There are multiple ways to do this, from going super-dynamic and creating them on the fly in a metaclass's `__getattribute__` (although that doesn't work for some special methods—see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup))
to generating source text to save in a `.py` file that you can then `import`. But the simplest solution is to create them in the class definition, something like this:

```
class MyVector:
    # ...

    def _make_op_method(op):
        def _op(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
                tmp = list()
                for i in self.l:
                    tmp.append(op(i. other))
                return Vector(tmp)
            raise VectorException("We can only {} a Vector by a scalar".format(
                op.__name__.strip('_'))
        _.op.__name__ = op.__name__
        return _op

    __mul__ = _make_op(operator.__mul__)
    __truediv__ = _make_op(operator.__truediv__)
    # and so on
```

---

You can get fancier and set `_op.__doc__` to an appropriate docstring that you generate (see [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) in the `stdlib` for some relevant code), and build `__rmul__` and `__imul__` the same way you build `__mul__`, and so on. And you can write a metaclass, class decorator, or function generator that wraps up some of the details if you're going to be doing many variations of the same thing. But this is the basic idea.

In fact, moving it outside the class makes it easier to eliminate even more repetition. Just define that `_op(self, other, op)` method in the class instead of locally inside `_make_op` and decorate the class with `@numeric_ops`, which you can define like this:

```
def numeric_ops(cls):
    for op in "mul truediv floordiv".split():  # "mul truediv floordiv ... ".split():
        def _op(self, other):
            return self._op(other, getattr(operator, op)
        _op.__name__ = f"__{op}__"
        setattr(cls, f"__{op}__", _op)
```

If you look at, e.g., `functions.total_ordering`, it does something similar to generate any missing ordering ops out of the ones that are there.

The `operator.mul`, etc., come from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module in the stdlib—they're just trivial functions where `operator.__mul__(x, y)` basically just calls `x * y`, and so on, made for when you need to pass around an operator expression as a function.

There are some examples of this kind of code in the stdlib—although far more examples of the related but much simpler `__rmul__ = __mul__`.

The key here is that there's no difference between names you create with `def` and names you create by assigning with `=`. Either way, `__mul__` becomes an attribute of the class, and its value is a function that does what you want. (And, similarly, there’s almost no difference between names you create during class definition and names you inject afterward.)

---

So, should you be doing this?

Well, DRY is important. If you copy-paste-edit a dozen times it’s not unlikely that you’ll screw up one of the edits and end up with a mod method that actually multiples and that (and a unit test that doesn’t catch it). And then, if you later discover a flaw in the implementation you copied and pasted a dozen times (as between the original and edited version of the question), you have to fix the same flaw in a dozen places, which is yet another potential bug magnet.

On the other hand, readability counts. If you don't understand how that works, you probably shouldn't be doing this, and should settle for Ramazan Polat's answer. (It's not quite as compact, or as efficient, but it's surely easier to understand.) After all, if the code isn’t obvious to you, the fact that you only have to fix a bug once instead of a dozen times is swamped by the fact that you don’t know how to fix it. And even if you do understand it, the cost of cleverness can often outweigh the benefits of DRY.

I think `total_ordering` shows about where you’d want to draw the line. If you’re doing this one time, you’re better off with the repetition, but if you’re doing it for multiple classes or in multiple projects, you’re probably better off abstracting the cleverness into a library that you can write once, exhaustive test with a variety of different classes, and then use over and over.

Comment: The metaclass `__getattribute__` approach wouldn't work; magic method lookup ignores that.

Comment: Probably want to pass `operator.mul` instead of `operator.__mul_`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why? Try `operator.__mul__ is operator.mul`. They're the exact same object. And I think `__mul__` is clearer for this case, because (a) we're implementing a `__mul__` method, and (b) it makes it more obvious that we're doing something that involves implementation stuff.

Comment: @abarnert for the same reason you generally avoid using dunder-attribute directly, if it is easy to avoid. i.e. using `next(some_iter)` instead of `some_iter.__next__()`, anyway, that's what the module docs recommend but I guess it's whatever floats your boat

Comment: @user2357112 Are you sure? I know Python reserves the right to skip any of the different steps for any special method lookup, but CPython does different things for three different groups of them. and I thought numeric methods were in the `type(obj).__getattribute__` group?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's a completely different case. Calling `next(some_iter)` allows the implementation to do something besides calling `some_iter.__next__()` under the covers. CPython doesn't actually do that, but it does in many similar cases—e.g., `iter(x)` doesn't just call `x.__iter__()`, it also has code to fall back to `__getitem__`. Calling `operator.__add__(a, b)` does not have the same problem as calling `a.__add__(b)`.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the "three different groups" thing. Some parts of the standard library do special method lookup weird - I remember `pickle` having some issues with that - but the C core of the interpreter is pretty consistent about always searching through the `__dict__`s of the types in an object's MRO. [Here's](https://ideone.com/jz3IUm) an example where `*` fails without ever invoking the metaclass's `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @user2357112: I get the "three different groups" from the CPython C and Python source code (although it's been a few years since I looked at it). There are three different ways of looking up special methods, which all have different behavior. It's not documented which ones are looked up which way; all; the only docs are the section I linked, which just says "implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type". This is intentionally vague (although the intention is more about, e.g., letting Jython do something different).

Comment: This code block should be within some `class` block, right? I think, assuming I understand correctly, that this would be much easier to read it you added that one line and an extra level of indentation, to see that you’re doing that assignment within the class definition. (And if you *aren’t* doing it within a class’s block, then this answer leaves me quite confused as to how these operators are getting assigned to the class.)

Comment: @KRyan Yes, this would be inside the class, directly substituting for the existing code inside the class in the question. However, you could just as easily have the code outside the class, and just do `MyClass.__mul__ =` instead of just `__mul__ =`. That’s actually cleaner in some cases—especially if you want to take it even farther and generate the methods from a list of names. I’ll edit the answer to explain more.

Comment: Reading this code, makes me dizzy! Still a valid answer tho.

Comment: @RamazanPolat That's the point of the conclusion: it's probably only worth doing this kind of cleverness if you can abstract that cleverness away into a library. Which is exactly what the Python stdlib does—see the dynamic but trickily clever code in the reusable `total_ordering` decorator vs. the simpler but more repetitive code in some of the `collections` classes. (it's also why I upvoted your answer, and recommended it in my conclusion.) All that being said, it's worth learning how to read and understand this code (even if you're never going to write it).

Answer (score 19):

Factorize code using [decorator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and [lambda function](https://pythonspot.com/python-lambda/):

```
class Vector:
    def __do_it(self, other, func):
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            tmp = list()
            for i in self.l:
                tmp.append(func(i, other))
            return Vector(tmp)
        raise ValueError("We can only operate a Vector by a scalar")

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__do_it(other, lambda i, o: i * o)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.__do_it(other, lambda i, o: i / o)

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return self.__do_it(other, lambda i, o: i // o)
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code could be as compact as below (juanpa.arrivillaga suggested to `return NotImplemented` instead of raising an exception):

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    #Vector([1, 2, 3]) * 5 => Vector([5, 10, 15])
    try:
        return Vector([i * other for i in self.l])
    except TypeError:
        return NotImplemented
```

Comment: This is all true, but it doesn't answer the question. You're still copying and pasting the same implementation, with one character changed for each version. And, if fact, your changes show exactly why that's a problem: because if he wants to make the fixes you're suggesting, he has to make those same fixes in every one of the methods. What are the odds that he'll make a typo in one of them and not catch it until after he's created reams of buggy output?

Answer (score 7):

The Strategy pattern is your friend here. I'll also touch on a couple of other ways you can clean up code.

You can read about the strategy pattern here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

You said "As you can see, every overloaded method is a copy/paste of the previous with just small changes." This is your hint to use this pattern. If you can make the small change into a function, then you can write the boilerplate code once and focus on the interesting parts.

```
class Vector:
    def _arithmitize(self, other, f, error_msg):
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            tmp = list()
            for a in self.l:
                tmp.append(func(a, other))
            return Vector(tmp)
        raise ValueError(error_msg)

    def _err_msg(self, op_name):
        return "We can only {} a vector by a scalar".format(opp_name)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._arithmitize(
            other, 
            lambda a, b: a * b, 
            self._err_msg('mul'))

    def __div__(self, other):
        return self._arithmitize(
            other, 
            lambda a, b: a / b, 
            self._err_msg('div'))
    # and so on ...
```

We can clean this up a little more with a list comprehension

```
class Vector:
    def _arithmetize(self, other, f, error_msg):
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            return Vector([f(a, other) for a in self.l])
        raise ValueError(error_msg)

    def _err_msg(self, op_name):
        return "We can only {} a vector by a scalar".format(opp_name)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(
            other, 
            lambda a, b: a * b, 
            self._err_msg('mul'))

    def __div__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(
            other, 
            lambda a, b: a / b, 
            self._err_msg('div'))
```

We can improve the type check

```
import numbers

class Vector:
    def _arithmetize(self, other, f, error_msg):
        if isinstance(other, number.Numbers):
            return Vector([f(a, other) for a in self.l])
        raise ValueError(error_msg)
```

We can use operators instead of writing lambdas:

```
import operators as op

class Vector:
    # snip ...
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(other, op.mul, self._err_msg('mul'))
```

So we end up with something like this:

```
import numbers
import operators as op

class Vector(object):
    def _arithmetize(self, other, f, err_msg):
        if isinstance(other, numbers.Number):
            return Vector([f(a, other) for a in self.l])
        raise ValueError(self._error_msg(err_msg))
    def _error_msg(self, msg):
        return "We can only {} a vector by a scalar".format(opp_name)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(op.mul, other, 'mul')

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(op.truediv, other, 'truediv')

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(op.floordiv, other, 'floordiv')

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(op.mod, other, 'mod')

    def __pow__(self, other):
        return self._arithmetize(op.pow, other, 'pow')
```

There are other ways you might dynamically generate these, but for a small set of functions like this, readability counts.

If you need to generate these dynamically, try something like this:

```
class Vector(object):
    def _arithmetize(....):
        # you've seen this already 

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        funcs = {
            '__mul__': op.mul, # note: this may not actually work with dunder methods. YMMV
            '__mod__': op.mod,
            ...
        }
        def g(self, other):
            try:
                return self._arithmetize(funcs[name],...)
             except:
                 raise NotImplementedError(...)
        return g
```

If you find this dynamic example does not work, check out [make operators overloading less redundant in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141878/make-operators-overloading-less-redundant-in-python/49142031#49142031), which handles the case of dynamically creating dunder_methods in most python implementations.

Comment: In you penultimate example, you don't need the `err_msg` argument to `arithimitize` - you can use `f.__name__` instead.  (i.e. `op.mul.__name__` is "mul").

Comment: Also, it should be "arithm**e**tize" (names are important)

Comment: The last version sadly won't work. Well, it won't work in CPython, and _probably_ won't work in any Python; the rules for special method lookup are (intentionally) vague. But unless you're writing, e.g., a proxy class that lazily generates methods the first time they're called, creating them at class creation time (as with `total_ordering`, or my answer) rather than lookup time is usually all the dynamicness you need, and more efficient and easier to reason about (if a bit more verbose and harder to initially code up), so this limitation usually isn't a problem.

Comment: @abarnert that's a good point. I've left a comment in there with a link to your answer. I think this still works if you need to implement some other interface that's not using special method names, so I've left it otherwise in place.

Comment: @munk: Yeah, if it didn't work for non-special-method names, `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` wouldn't  exist. And dynamic proxies (for bridges, ORMs, RPCs, etc.) often need it. I wasn't suggesting you remove it from your answer, just making a comment.